# windows - Windows broken since I installed Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows, uefi, windows-10

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 as a dual boot on a laptop along Windows 10. Both systems worked fine for about a week, but now whenever I launch Windows, it starts by trying to repair itself, but fails and only then can I choose to go to Windows directly without repairing. All the questions about this type of problem I've read mention Windows not being able to boot afterwards, but for me Windows boots fine (slowly, but it works). What's the explanation for this and is there a solution?

What I don't get is that my other computer also starts up in repair mode even though I haven't installed any Linux distro, I've only tried a live version of BunsenLabs (which didn't work; I choose to try the fail-safe live version and part of the screen just turned black, so I turned the computer off by ). Is this a different problem or the same? I've tried to restore through a restore point, but apparently I don't have any. One difference with my other computer is that I can stop the repair before it starts on the first try, whereas I have to wait until the second boot to stop it in the first case.

Comment: Did you shrink Windows too much? NTFS needs about 30% free to run well, and at 10% free it will be so slow you just about cannot do a defrag. Also is Windows fast start up off (which sets hibernation flag). Grub will not boot hibernated Windows, so you then can only directly boot from UEFI boot menu. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: @oldfred Both partitions are much bigger than needed, so that doesn't seem to be the problem. Fast start-up is off on Windows.

Comment: Boot Repair -Also handles LVM, GPT, separate /boot and UEFI dual boot, only use ppa download into Ubuntu live installer.
May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: I don't know why, since I didn't change anything, but my computer doesn't boot in repair mode anymore. Thank you for your help nonetheless @oldfred @janmyszkier!

Comment: Are you able to boot Ubuntu live installer in live mode & run Boot-Repair's report?

Answer (score 0):

What seems to happen is your boot manager (grub I guess) incorrectly marked your `Windows recovery` partition as `Windows system` partition.

You just need to edit grub entries and point it to the correct partition.
If you're not sure `gparted` and `blkid` should help you identifying the current partitions to compare them with current grub config for correctness.

Comment: According to Grub Customizer, Windows boots on Windows Boot Manager on the EFI system partition (/boot/efi). Should it boot on the Basic data partition that contains Windows instead or is the current configuration ok?

Comment: If UEFI system, all boot loaders are in ESP - efi system partition which is FAT32 wtih boot flag and/or esp flag. No boot flag on any other partition.